# Overview of upcoming flights from a specific airport?

Tags: air-travel, airports, flight-status

My flight from Antananarivo (TNR) to Paris with Air Madagascar tonight was canceled. My travel agent is not really working in the weekend and I'm curious if there are any flights I could take from TNR that would take me home before Tuesday afternoon.

I tried looking for flights through Kayak and Skyscanner but I'm not getting a clear idea about the next flights out of TNR that would get me closer to home, e.g. to Nairobi and then would also show flights from Nairobi.

Is there a general way to find out the upcoming flights from a specific airport?

(The TNR website is actually [showing departures](http://antananarivoairport.com/departures/) now but it wasn't working earlier, or well, might also be the internet connection here. But ideally I don't want to go through different websites and get departure information from airports across the world in one place. And actually the flight information they're showing on the site is inaccurate, my flight is still showing up as scheduled.)

Answer (score 1):

flightstats.com can show [upcoming flights by airport](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByAirport.do?airportQueryType=0).

The TNR website is actually showing an iframe from flightstats.com. This also means you can't trust this data 100%, since my canceled flight is still indicated as *Scheduled* on there, although I suspect that the reliability of the data is a bit higher in developed countries.